# VueJs Observer instead of Object

Tags: vue.js, object, vuejs2, observers, vue-reactivity

I'm quite new to VueJs and stuck on what is probably a silly mistake. Yet, I can't figure it out.

**What I'm trying to do :**
I created a form component that is use either for creating element or editing existing ones.
If the form is called with a populated Object as prop, it's editing ; if it's called with an empty Object, it's creating.
Note that the "isEditing" flag is for convenience but should not be necessary in the end, and that some parts of the code have been removed for readability.

Form component call :

```html
<ingredient-form :parent-ingredient="ingredient" :is-editing="isEditing" @callback="getAllIngredients" @close="props.close" />
```

Opening method :

```js
data () {
  return {
    isModalActive: false,
    ingredient: {},
    isEditing: false,
    // ...
  }
},
// ...
methods: {
  openIngredientForm (ingredient) {
    if (Object.keys(ingredient).length > 0 && ingredient.constructor === Object) {
      this.ingredient = ingredient
      this.isEditing = true
    } else {
      this.ingredient = {}
      this.isEditing = false
    }
    this.isModalActive = true
  }
}
```

Up 'til here, everything works. The modal appears, no error in console, and the editing or creating status is clear.

**What fails :**
I must be doing something wrong in the Component's code. Editing works as expected, the forms gives back a proper Object which is sent to backend through an Axios.put call.
But creating a new element fails, as it gives an Observer instead of an Object, which leads to Axios/MySQL crashing.

Here is the Component's code :

```html
<template>
  <form novalidate @submit.prevent="addIngredientToDB">
    <div class="modal-card">
      <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title">
          Nouvel ingrédient
        </p>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="delete"
          @click="$emit('close')"
        />
      </header>
      <section class="modal-card-body">
        <!-- ... -->
        <div class="form-group bottom-margin" :class="{ 'form-group-error': $v.ingredient.ing_name.$error }">
          <b-field
            label="Nom"
            :type="{ 'is-danger' : $v.ingredient.ing_name.$error }"
          >
            <b-input
              v-model.trim="$v.ingredient.ing_name.$model"
              type="text"
            />
          </b-field>
          <!-- ... -->
        </div>

        <b-field label="Calories pour 100g (cal)">
          <b-numberinput
            v-model.number="ingredient.ing_cal"
            step="5"
            min-step="0.01"
            placeholder="100"
          />
        </b-field>
        <!-- ... -->
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <b-button
          label="Annuler"
          @click="$emit('close')"
        />
        <b-button
          :label="buttonLabel"
          :type="buttonType"
          @click="addIngredientToDB"
        />
      </footer>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

And corresponding JS :

```js
import { required, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  props: {
    isEditing: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    parentIngredient: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      buttonLabel: 'Ajouter',
      buttonType: 'is-success',
      submitStatus: null,
      ingredient: {
        ing_name: '' // to enable vuelidate reactivity
      },
      errors: []
    }
  },
  validations: {
    ingredient: {
      ing_name: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(3)
      }
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    if (Object.keys(this.parentIngredient).length !== 0 || this.parentIngredient.constructor !== Object) {
      this.ingredient = { ...this.parentIngredient }
      this.buttonLabel = 'Modifier'
      this.buttonType = 'is-info'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addIngredientToDB () {
      this.$v.$touch()
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.submitStatus = 'ERROR'
      } else {
        this.submitStatus = 'VALID'
        this.ingredient.ing_name = this.ingredient.ing_name.toLowerCase()
        // console.log(this.ingredient) gives an __Observer__
        console.log(this.ingredient)
        if (!this.isEditing) {
          await this.$axios
            .post('/api/ingredient', this.ingredient)
            .then((response) => {
              this.ingredient.id = response.data.insertId
              // Okay
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              // Not okay
              })
            })
        } else {
          // The rest works as when editing, this.ingredient is a correct object, not an Observer
        }

        this.$emit('callback')
        this.$emit('close')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What I tried :**
At this point, it's hard to list what I tried.
I tried to use $set, Object.assign, JSON.stringify/parse... No matter what, I get an Observer (which actually contains the data).
I don't get why it works in one case and not the other.
I feel that I could find a workaround but I'd really like to understand what I did wrong. Though at this point, my code is getting heavier and overly complicated every passing minute ;).

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Sounds like you want to have some sort of editor modal? In this case I'd suggest to not modify the object in question directly but to operate on a clone. If the user wants to save the changes you'd emit the cloned object like this: `this.$emit("input", this.clone)`

Comment: The editing process does work. It's using a shadow clone ```javascript this.ingredient = { ...this.parentIngredient } ``` 
But on the other side, creating a new element fails.

Comment: @LucSimons Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19 I'm struggling a lot more than I thought to get a codesandbox-nuxt running. Will edit if finally getting it up 'n running.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to require Nuxt. You can use a Vue Codesandbox: https://vue.new. If you really need a Nuxt sandbox: https://nuxt.new or https://stackblitz.com/fork/github/nuxt/starter/tree/stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You might parse the observable before sending it to the Axios.

```
const parsedIngredient = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ingredient))
```

Then send `parsedIngredient` to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Though, even adding :
```javascript  
const parsedIngredient = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ingredient))
console.log(parsedIngredient)
```
Still display an Observer. Don't get why.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot ?

Comment: My bad, after restarting nuxt, it does work. I do get `console.log(parsedIngredient) // {ing_name: "randomname"}`. But backend API still send back "'ing_name' cannot be null".
I will look into it. 

Could you explain why this step is requiered while adding a new element ? I'm missing the logic behind. Why can't I use directly this.ingredient, which would make more sense (to me at least, might be wrong !). That would be great